# How to make Android 2.3 to use voice recognition without the need of internet?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, voice-recognition

On my Samsung Galaxy Y Duos, GT-S6102B, you can press a button to talk something instead of writing it. It is a wonderful behavior, but it functions only when using a internet connection - well, I see it functioning only with Wi-Fi connection...

But I would like to use it offline... Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I use a third party app which can handle recorded voice tags.
I use Cyberon Voice Speed dial for which voice tags can be records for contacts or programs.

For bluetooth headset/car conenctivity i use Bluetooth Application Launcher.

This is set to open Voice Speed dialler when i press the blue tooth button to connect.  Holding the blue tooth button for 4 seconds disconnects and closes the app.  (i have to configure it futhter since disconnecting doesn;t yet hang up the phone though...)

Sorry - i just realized you needed to dictate to your phone.  Maybe there also a third pary app that does that.

Benzene

Comment: The app you recommended is only for dial some numbers.

Comment: I found "Cyberon Voice Commander", but is also paid and does not inform about use when offline...